# Reconciling Nondeterministic and Probabilistic Decision Rules

Tags: expected-value, finance, robust, decision-theory, risk

I've been getting a bit stuck recently on how to reconcile the two seemingly-competing ideas of nondeterministic and probabilistic decision rules.

As an example:

Let $t=0$ denote the current time and let $t=T$ denote some future time.

Let $w_t$ denote our wealth at time $t$.

Assume we have a market with one risk-free asset, $B$, and a collection of various other risky assets such options, futures, equity, etc.

Let $B_t$ denote the value of our risk-free asset at time $t$. We take $B_0 \in (0,1)$ and $B_T=1$.

Say we want to decide how to allocate our wealth into these various assets, perhaps more than once, such that we optimize some functional of our future wealth (create a trading strategy).

If we try to apply only nondeterministic decision rules and use the strategy that maximizes the minimum of $w_T$, we would probably end up putting everything into the risk-free asset meaning we would have a guaranteed, but very low return as $B_0$ tends to be close to 1 in practice.

On the other end, if we apply probabilistic decision rules such as attempting to say, choose the strategy that maximizes the expected value of the logarithm of $w_T$, we would probably have something that falls much more in line with conventional balancing of risk versus reward as we would likely choose some other strategy that doesn't predominantly invest in the risk-free asset and also somewhat reflects the utility of the wealth as the more dollars you have, the "less" a single dollar is worth to you. However, assuming our chosen strategy puts little to nothing into the risk-free asset, we open ourselves up to a massive risk in the form of tail events, model risk, epistemic uncertainty, etc. since however unlikely, our risky assets *could* lose most/all of their value?

Is there any way to reconcile these two sets of decision rules since they do seem to individually contribute helpful attributes such as security/safety on one end and likely reward on the other? Would it just be on us to create a decision rule that is say, a weighted average of nondeterministic and probabilistic decision rules that reflects our preferences? Or are there some "optimal" criteria we can aspire to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no disagreement between deterministic vs randomized strategies. You can pick a [risk averse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion) deterministic strategy by always betting on the asset related with the smallest loss. You can pick a deterministic greedy strategy, where you always pick an asset that has the highest possible payoff. You can pick a randomized risk-averse strategy that picks the least risky assets with the highest probability. Or you can pick a greedy randomized strategy where you pick the assets with the highest possible payoffs with the highest probability.

There is also no disagreement between the strategies, just that each of them optimizes a different thing. All the possible outcomes should be considered by your [utility function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility). If you are considering only the short-term gains, no surprise that the strategy can not be the best long-term. If you want to weigh different risks and outcomes, happening with different probabilities, this is what [expected utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_utility_hypothesis) does. And of course, the expected utility also has its limitations, see e.g. the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox). What I'm trying to say is that if you dive deeper into [decision theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_theory), it already considers all such problems.

As for combining strategies, yes it is doable. For example, you could use a randomized strategy that $\epsilon\%$ of the time plays safe, and $100 - \epsilon\%$ picks the risky strategy to balance the two. To pick the $\epsilon$, you again need the expected utility, so you can balance the risks based on their probabilities.

There are [many good books on decision theory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/448652/35989), I recommend you pick one and go through it.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer and helpful references! I skimmed that, searched them up, and could've missed one or two, but wanted to ask if you, off the top of your head, know of any free-without-access-gating resources on decision theory? It's okay if they really only address the designing of a utility function, but comprehensive is great, too :)

Comment: @QMath I'm afraid I don't know any resources that I'd recommend and are free to access online.

Comment: No problem at all! Thank You for the wealth of information provided so far :)